# Foreign money comes to my account

Tags: financial-literacy, money-transfer, scams

A foreign friend wants to help me by transferring money to my savings account. I  got an email from RBI telling me go for online procedure through a link.  After completing 3 out of 2 steps, asking me for international transfer code. Then I reply to that mail. Another mail comes to me saying that to get international transfer code I should deposit 45000 INR that I can't pay. Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your foreign "friend" is trying to steal 45000INR from you. In case you haven't guessed - he's not your friend.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Why should it cost you money for your friend to transfer money to you?  **How long have you known this friend??**

Comment: "*I got an email from RBI telling me go for online procedure through a link.*" How did you determine that the email was from RBI?

Comment: Hopefully the first 1-2 steps you completed at that "RBI" site did not have you providing your personal information. Or else this may not be over yet.

Answer (score 8):

This is a scam. Your "friend" is trying to steal money from you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a scam. No transfer code is required from RBI.

They are trying to steal money from you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scam.

For someone to send money to you - you should get the money first. Even if the bank or Paypal charges fees, those fees are taken out by the broker while the money is in transit. The transferring bank or company would take their fee (usually 1-5%) when it passes through them to you.

This scam works by tricking you into paying money for a code up front. If you pay this code either won't work or will never appear. Your supposed friend will now have your 45000 rupees and will buy himself something nice. You will never be paid.

Another sign of a scam is that RBI is the Reserve Bank of India, https://www.rbi.org.in/ . The **RESERVE** Bank of India does not appear to handle retail banking, it is a bank run with the government to effect large-scale monetary policy.

In the highly unlikely event that this is not a scam and is really a friend helping you out by giving you money, ask them if they can pay the fee and take it out from the money they are sending you instead of having you pay it. For example if they are sending you 100000INR they would take the 45000INR off the top and you would get 55000INR.